# C++ GDI+ memory leak in own class

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks, gdi+

I am searching for the memory leak(s) in this code.
I am new to GDI+ and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.
The class you see below gets called in a loop in my main function.
Each loop iteration I push an other vector to the function.
Everything is working fine except there is a memory leak.
I tried the program cppCheck to find the leak but it found no memory leaks :/
My last chance to fix the problem is to ask someone who has more experience than me with GDI+

Thank you very much for the help and sorry for the long code :)

```
#include "helper.h"

Gui::Gui(const TCHAR* fileName) {
    this->fileName = fileName;
}

void Gui::drawGui(Gdiplus::Bitmap* image, std::vector<std::wstring> &vec) {

    // Init graphics
    Gdiplus::Graphics* graphics = Gdiplus::Graphics::FromImage(image);

    Gdiplus::Pen penWhite (Gdiplus::Color::White);
    Gdiplus::Pen penRed   (Gdiplus::Color::Red);
    Gdiplus::SolidBrush redBrush(Gdiplus::Color(255, 255, 0, 0));
    penRed.SetWidth(8);

    unsigned short marginTop = 15;
    unsigned short marginLeft = 5;
    unsigned short horizontalBarsizeStart = marginLeft + 60;


    for (unsigned short iter = 0; iter < 8; iter++) {
        // Draw text
        std::wstring coreLabel = L"Core " + std::to_wstring(iter) + L':';
        Gdiplus::Font myFont(L"Arial", 12);
        Gdiplus::PointF origin(marginLeft, marginTop - 10);
        graphics->DrawString(coreLabel.c_str(), coreLabel.length(), &myFont, origin, &redBrush);

        // Draw CPU lines
        unsigned short horizontalBarsizeEnd = horizontalBarsizeStart + std::stoi(vec.at(iter)); // 100 == Max cpu load
        graphics->DrawLine(&penRed, horizontalBarsizeStart, marginTop, horizontalBarsizeEnd, marginTop);

        // Draw border
        Gdiplus::Rect rect(horizontalBarsizeStart, marginTop - 5, 100, 8);
        graphics->DrawRectangle(&penWhite, rect);

        // Next element
        marginTop += 17;
    }
}


bool Gui::SetColorBackgroundFromFile(std::vector<std::wstring> &vec) {

    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
    // Initialize GDI+.
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);

    HDC hdc = GetDC(NULL);

    // Load the image. Any of the following formats are supported: BMP, GIF, JPEG, PNG, TIFF, Exif, WMF, and EMF
    Gdiplus::Bitmap* image = Gdiplus::Bitmap::FromFile(this->fileName, false);

    if (image == NULL) {
        return false;
    }

    // Draw the gui
    this->drawGui(image, vec);

    // Get the bitmap handle
    HBITMAP hBitmap = NULL;
    Gdiplus::Status status = image->GetHBITMAP(RGB(0, 0, 0), &hBitmap);
    if (status != Gdiplus::Ok) {
        return false;
    }

    BITMAPINFO bitmapInfo = { 0 };
    bitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);

    // Check what we got
    int ret = GetDIBits(hdc, hBitmap, 0, 0, NULL, &bitmapInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    if (LOGI_LCD_COLOR_WIDTH != bitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth || LOGI_LCD_COLOR_HEIGHT != bitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight) {
        std::cout << "Oooops. Make sure to use a 320 by 240 image for color background." << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    bitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    bitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight = -bitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight; // this value needs to be inverted, or else image will show up upside/down

    BYTE byteBitmap[LOGI_LCD_COLOR_WIDTH * LOGI_LCD_COLOR_HEIGHT * 4]; // we have 32 bits per pixel, or 4 bytes

    // Gets the "bits" from the bitmap and copies them into a buffer 
    // which is pointed to by byteBitmap.
    ret = GetDIBits(hdc, hBitmap, 0,
    -bitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight, // height here needs to be positive. Since we made it negative previously, let's reverse it again.
    &byteBitmap,
    (BITMAPINFO *)&bitmapInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    LogiLcdColorSetBackground(byteBitmap); // Send image to LCD

    // delete the image when done 
    if (image) {
        delete image;
        image = NULL;
        Gdiplus::GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken); // Shutdown GDI+
    }
return true;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `drawGui()` you're leaking the `graphics` object. This line creates a new `Gdiplus::Graphics` object:

```
Gdiplus::Graphics* graphics = Gdiplus::Graphics::FromImage(image);
```

But nowhere do you call `delete graphics` to delete it once you're done with it.

In `SetColorBackgroundFromFile`, you're leaking the DC.

```
HDC hdc = GetDC(NULL);
```

This gets a DC for the screen, but nowhere do you call `ReleaseDC(NULL, hdc);` to free it.

In the same function, you are creating an `HBITMAP` using the following call:

```
Gdiplus::Status status = image->GetHBITMAP(RGB(0, 0, 0), &hBitmap);
```

But nowhere do you call `DeleteObject(hBitmap);` to free it.

You also have the problem that in case of errors, your code can return without doing necessary cleanup. E.g. if the `GetHBITMAP` call fails, you return immediately and will leak the `image` object that you created a few lines above.

Comment: Perfect so far :) But ReleaseDC(hdc); is not working

Comment: @TheCoder Sorry, that should have been `ReleaseDC(NULL, hdc);`

Comment: Thank you very much, you saved the day!

Comment: @TheCoder  It would be worth your while to use RAII techniques to minimize, if not eliminate these errors.  Your current code has multiple return points -- any code changes and you forget to delete your resources, you have a leak.  Using RAII removes these issues:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321511/what-is-meant-by-resource-acquisition-is-initialization-raii